# how to flatten list ( multi dimention list to one dimention list ) in haskell

Tags: haskell, flatten

I want to flatten the any dimension list to 1 dimention list
this code is working for all testcase except for empty 2d list

```
import Prelude hiding (foldl)


foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldl fun init list =
    case list of
        [] -> init
        (head:tail) -> foldl fun (fun init head) tail


flatten_l :: [[a]] -> [a]
flatten_l xss = foldl (\ ys xs -> ys ++ xs) [] xss


main = interact (\ s -> show $ flatten_l [[1,2,3], [4,5], [6], [], [7,8,9], []] )
```

this is not working for input - [[ ]]

`main = interact (\ s -> show $ flatten_l [[]] )`

Comment: What does "dimension" mean to you? It doesn't seem to be the same as what most people mean by that word -- `flatten_l` only reduces the dimension *by* 1 in the way most people mean "dimension", it doesn't reduce the dimension *to* 1. What does "not working" mean? What output do you get? What do you expect to get instead?

Comment: for input [[]] , i am getting error - Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.    the output i want is []

Answer (score 3):

The list `[]` might be shown in different ways depending on its type<sup>*</sup>. The most important example of this is that `[] :: String` is shown as `""`, while for most other list types it is `[]`.

In order to choose between these behaviors, you must tell GHC which type you want your `[]` to have. Compare:

```
-- ambiguous type variable error
main = print []

-- works, prints ""
main = print ([] :: [Char])

-- works, prints []
main = print ([] :: [Int])
```

<sup>*</sup> Actually, `[]` is not special in this regard -- any list may be shown differently depending on its type. However, it's rare to see this problem with lists that have elements, because it's rare for the elements to be polymorphic. So the way that `[]` is special is actually that it doesn't have any elements to give the compiler a hint about its type, not that its instances depend on its type.